# CubeSat redundant reaction wheel

Tags: reaction-wheel

3 reaction wheels are used to control the orientation of the satellite. If one wheel fails, how does the redundant wheel take its place?

Comment: I believe that the redundant wheel is often oriented in such a way that it will have influences on all of the 3 axes the other wheels are running on. If one wheel fails, then all the attitude maneuvers would be recalculated to account for the redundant wheel making up for the failed one.